# Problem finding the length and factors of a finite p-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to find the length and factors of a finite p-group $G$. My reasoning is as follows:

As $G$ is a finite p-group then $|G| = p^n$ for some $n \ge 0$. By the Sylow theorems I can get a collection of p-subgroups $\{1\} \le H_p \le \cdots \le H_{p_n}$ where $H_{p^i}$ is a subgroup of order $p^i$. The only thing I need to conclude my search is to proof normality.

How can I proof normality in the series?

Comment: Since the centre of a nontrivial $p$-group is nontrivial, and any subgroup of the centre is normal, you can find a normal subgroup $H_p$ of order $p$. Now apply induction to $G/H_p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Derek Holt pointed out to solve my problem I just need the following proposition.

> Let $G$ be a p-group with $|G| = p^n$. Proof that for each $0 \le k
>  \le n$ there exists a normal subgroup $H \trianglelefteq G$ such that
>   $|H| = p^k$.

Which can be proved using induction and Burnside's theorem on the size of the center of a non-trivial finite p-group.